# How to pass kerberos cred from Java

Tags: java, curl, hadoop-yarn, kerberos, kill

we are tyring to kill the yarn job from Java using http put call
with out kerberos it was working..
but after we enabling kerberos we are getting 403 error

we are able to generate kerberos credentials on App server. But how can we pass those credentials from java code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not understand your kerberos implement.
I suggest you my general implement.
When you input your security authentication information,you may get a temporary authentication token, you could transfer this through the http header,and  get the http header on your java app  and then verify it with the temporary authentication token you have saved before.
If you really don’t know how to do this implement functions ,maybe you could add more detail of your java program.Such as the java version ,your http communication framework etc.